# Why does my Fluid simulation look like there is a floor where there isn't one?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to set up a fluid simulation to flow down this guys arm but it keeps ending up looking like this. Is there something I need to apply to make it not do this?

Additionally, I can't seem to adjust the world size in the fluid settings, as the hand is supposed to be giant. 
[image: Fluid Simulation branching off of arm]

Comment: Could it be, that the "floor" is from your fluid-domain?

Comment: Make the fluid domain larger.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could cause this to happen in fluid simulations. 1) Your domain is smaller than your obstacle, so your fluid boundaries are smaller. 2) You have an invisible obstacle that is beneath the fluid inflow. (unlikely). 3) You need to change the location of the fluid simulation bake. 4) You need to set the simulation quality to a higher number. I hope these settings work for you!